# Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '() -> ()'

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass a function as a parameter in Swift. In order to do that, I defined my function that takes a callback parameter as:

```
func foo(callback: () -> () = { _ in }) { callback() }
```

I then define another function that I will use:

```
func toBeCalled() -> () { 
   print("hello world") 
}

foo(toBeCalled())
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '() -> ()'
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I have tried multiple things including using Void.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass the function not the result of that function:

```
foo(toBeCalled)
```

`toBeCalled` has type `() -> ()` but when you write `toBeCalled()`, the function gets executed and you get the return type `()`.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that earlier and had a different error but it worked this time.

Comment: And if `toBeCalled` has any parameters you can do `{toBeCalled(parameter)}`